# How to remember positions within multiple files in Media Player Classic?

Tags: software-rec, media-player, playlists, multiple-instances

I tend to have many instances of Media Player Classic (Best Player in my opinion) open because I switch from one video to another, then pause and go back to it later (as in, hours or days).

Is there a known application that "remembers" my last viewing point and lets me navigate through different videos all in the same application without me having to run multiple instances and pause and ALT + TAB to move to the other vids?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No need to search for any other application. The awesome Media Player Classic has a built-in feature that remembers last viewing position of all supported media files. To enable this, go to View -> Options. In history section, check both 'remember dvd position' and 'remember file position' options, and save changes. Do note, MPC remembers position of only those files that are in the recent files list.

[image: Media Player files position]