# A media player which records/logs media files played

Tags: windows-7, logging, media-player

I (Windows OS user) am currently listening to some audio tutorials (mostly mp3 formats). **The tutorial set contains hundreds of media files.** I am requiring a function in the media player which helps me to know what I have already listed and what tutorials are left?

Is there a media player which can logs files played? Or, is there any way to achieve this using the common media players such as [AIMP](http://www.aimp2.us/), [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), [Windows media player](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-media-player/), [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/) and so on.

**EDIT**

It is not sufficient for me to know what files are played and how often. As I am listening to these tutorials on my PC I cannot always keep the media player open. I may need to restart my PC at times. So, how will I know when I come back which tutorial I was listening to and at what position. The statistics regarding the frequency of the file and when it was last played is not so useful to me. This is because I will not have the info of the position where I stopped. I have to go through the files and sort them as per `last played`. But these are not so helpful.

*Of course I can just maintain a log book but I was looking for a program to automatically do the logging (last played and the position I stopped it was stopped at) for me.*

Comment: I did something similar but I'm not putting it as an answer as it wasn't really any good. What I did was to sign up to http://www.podomatic.com and create my own podcast with just me as an subscriber. That way iTunes and my iPhone automaticly kept track of what I had listened to. It worked but I never used it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [1by1](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/1by1.html#dwn) does it. You need to enable the log by pressing F6 and then selecting log/scrobble before you begin to play anything...
[image]
 Then when you play your mp3 files, you need to go press ctrl+shift+L to get the log displayed as illustrated below.

[image]

and then you see this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [foobar 2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) with the plugin [foo playcount](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Components/Playback_Statistics_v3.x_%28foo_playcount%29). It gives you statistics about what you have played, when you have played it and how often.

---

According to [this post on ehow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_5875543_delete-count-windows-media-player.html) Windows Media Player is supposed to have a play count that you can use to sort your library. I don't have Win7 right now, but I suggest you look into that as well because it is the easiest way in my opinion.

---

**Update:**

[Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) can remember the last position of any file it was playing when closed. See [How to remember positions within multiple files in Media Player Classic?](https://superuser.com/questions/410438/how-to-remember-positions-within-multiple-files-in-media-player-classic) for an explanation. I don't think it can handle an index of all files, though.

Comment: I do not actually need any information on every file's statistics but information pertaining to which file was played last and before...

Comment: If it knows how often you have listened to it, it also knows which ones you haven't heard. What `number > 1` it shows you can just ignore. If you sort by `number played` you can clearly distinguish between the ones you've heard and the ones that are left.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Please see: I have edited my original question

Comment: @Stat-R: I updated my answer.